# Using C# parseInt in Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
<div class="rep_td0">@(parseInt(d.RowKey.substr(2, 2)) + "." + parseInt(d.RowKey.substr(4, 2)))</div>
```

Getting an error saying that:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'parseInt' does not exist in the current context
```

I thought this would work but can't understand why I get the error message. Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you r mixing java-script `parseInt` method with C# code - try `int.Parse` in C# code!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do `int.Parse(d.RowKey.substr(2, 2))`?